# Flutter i am not able to run the project

Tags: flutter

//here is my main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home:SplashScreen(),
  ));  
  class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
  }

  class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
     @override
  void initState (){
    super.initState();
    // TODO initial state stuff
    new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
  }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body:new Center(
          child:new Image.asset('images/backgroungimage.png'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

//here is the error

```
  Compiler message:
    file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:740:25: Error: Type 'PhoneNumberLoginPagee' not found.
        this.primary = true,PhoneNumberLoginPagee home,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:740:25: Error: 'PhoneNumberLoginPagee' isn't a type.
        this.primary = true,PhoneNumberLoginPagee home,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Compiler failed on D:\flutterProjects\sampleapp\lib/main.dart
     9.4s
    Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I wrote a code to create page called phoneNumberLoginPage after that i deleted the code.When i try to run the project in terminal its showing this message

Comment: could be a typo error, are you sure its `PhoneNumberLoginPagee` and not `PhoneNumberLoginPage`

Comment: yes its phoneNumberLoginPagee only.please tell me the solution for this

Comment: could you show how your are calling the PhoneNumberLoginPagee from main.dart since it is failing to compile there

Comment: i deleted the code. i am not calling phoneNumberLoginPagee anywhere

Comment: post your main.dart code. Seems like you are not passing the correct parameter to the Scaffold since its expecting something else

Comment: please check my updated code

Comment: I do not see any problem within your code. Try cleaning up your cache using `flutter clean` in the terminal and re-try.

Comment: i tried its not working

Comment: First of all, when you update a code please update the error messages too. Secondly, are you sure that you added the images to your assets?